# Application works via ip address but not via hostname

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I host my web app in IIS. The application is windows authenticated. The application is accessible if i use the host IP address but not when i use the host name. also this happens only from specific machines. I am able to access normally with host name from other machines.

Please help me resolving the same

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the HOST name is resolvable via DNS.  You might need to add an entry to your Hosts file.  C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts.

Comment: we did this in the hosted server. We added the host name to the host file. but still i am unable to access with hostname in some machines. After adding entry i flused the dns and then tried but no use . i am stil getting the same issue.

Comment: When you ping the host URL from the command line, does it resolve and resolve correctly?

Comment: does this host file entry has to be made in the hosted server or in the machine from which i am accessing the Site?

Comment: The machine from which you are accessing the site.  DNS Resolution seems to be your issue.  For your client machines, you have to ensure that when you type in "JayakumarsWebSite", the name gets resolved to "192.16.17.1".  I think you have 2 choices to make that happen.  You make the change in that machines DNS server, so the DNS server knows where your site is, or you can add the entry to your client machines host file.